# php, url rewrite, how can I get a string from GET if the url doesn't have "?"?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to build a php website and I would like to remove all the strings that make the url to seem dynamic.
 However I still need to get information through GET so basically I don't know how to do that because I need to pass a parameter to $_GET request which obviously would be dynamic . For example I may have www.domain.com/mobile_phones  where mobile_phones would be the parameter/information that I should get .
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this through a process called "routing". Normally you set up rewrite rule to forward everything to a single entry point - `index.php` then `index.php` intializes youre application witch makes use of some kind of routing class. This routing class compares the `REQUEST_URI` to a list of known patterns. When it matches i pattern it takes car of parsing out all the variables form the `URI`.

On the other end of things, to generate the proper urls wihtin the app there are usually a number of helpers that take a series of parameters along with a controller/action and generate a URL based on the same routing rules.

Take a look at the `Zend_Controller` package from Zend framework for a good example.

Answer (score 1):

URL rewriting works by translating the received URL string into a more suitable format, including get parameters.  For example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9])/.*$ index.php?id=$1
```

This will translate a string that's says, say `example.com/1234/my-page` to example.com/`index.php?id=1234` and id will be accessible directly from the `$_GET` array.

Comment: This will indeed work for simple things but when you need to transform: `/something/else/1` to `?action=something&module=else&id=1` and don want a set of rewrite rules for each individual endpoint it takes infrastructure on the scripting side.